# Need a Campfire-quality integrated chat system for a large site

Tags: web-apps, javascript, php, chat, mysql

I'd like to integrate a chatroom product/service into a typical PHP web app with thousands of users. We need (ideally):

- Private rooms with unique URLs
- Can invite other users
- Users can access full room history
- Upload attachments to rooms
- Assign users moderation abilities

I think Campfire could be great but they appear to cap users to 100 and we'll have 1000s (and integration doesn't look straightforward).

We're currently using CometChat, but it has several large shortcomings we don't have time to fix (e.g. rooms don't have URLs, no full history).

We have dev resources to integrate most anything and possibly a budget of a few thousand.